# How do I find good photography locations around Nottinghamshire/Derbyshire?

Tags: landscape, nature

I'm looking for some photography locations in Nottinghamshire/Derbyshire for landscape and nature.  Are there any helpful tools or techniques for locating and researching photography sites before visiting a locale?  What locations would give examples of these things to look for?

Comment: On downvotes and close votes, see discussion at https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/photo-location-tips-on-or-off-topic. I don't think we have complete community consensus on this. I'm not sure I have the same opinion I did years ago, though... this does tend towards being a list-type question.

Comment: @mattdm because of that meta question, i'm going to have a go answering it, but do it as a community wiki to allow others to expand rather than more and more answers to be posted.

Comment: OP. Have you considered using something like Trip Advisor to see the best things to do in these areas?

Comment: I voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based". To me, a question that asks "can anyone recommend..." sets off the shopping flag in my head. Of course, since an actual product or service wasn't being requested, that's not the correct close tag, but many of the same issues exist: these questions tend toward list-making; and they generate discussion rather than point towards resolution of the question.

Comment: Also, this seems to meet the "avoid asking subject questions where: every answer is equally valid: 'What’s your favorite ______?'" yardstick at [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Not to mention the part about being 'too localised'.

Comment: question states "how to find nice place" and "what are nice places". So the answer should be something like "look at google maps" or "open a local travel guide"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the specifics of location limit its usefulness. Asking a more general "how do you research good photography spots for a travel destination" wording would be more useful.

Comment: What's a "photography location"?

Comment: @inkista - a limited scope does not make a question off-topic.  We wouldn't remove use of camera models since they may limit the usefulness of the question.  "Too Localized" was taken off the list of close reasons years ago because the realization was reached that being of a small level of interest or niche isn't really a good reason to disallow a question.  It might not get much attention, but that's ok.

Comment: More information about the original intent of Too Localized and it's reason for removal is available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).  The general gist is that it was for things only helpful to the person asking.  ("Do my work for me" questions.)  Last time I checked there are more than one person living in or visiting the area and taking pictures, so it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous places in and around Nottingham itself.
There is Attenborough Nature Reserve, Highfields, Colwick Country Park, Wollaton Park.
I love taking Landscapes and would happily talk more with you.
Steve.

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions in no particular order:

- [The Peak District](http://www.peakdistrict.gov.uk/): National park coverings 555 square miles mainly in North Derbyshire but stretching into Cheshire, Staffordshire and Yorkshire. Despite the name lacks peaks but has rounded hills, plateaus, limestone gorges and sharp 'gritstone' edges. Plenty of attractions are also within this area.
- [Chatsworth House](https://www.chatsworth.org/): Stately home and seat of the Duke and Duchess of Derbyshire. Situated in it's own estate (open all year round) containing a country park, woodland, landscaped gardens and other interesting features like the cascade water feature.

Comment: As I'm local (Derby) I'll agree to these :-)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I got dragged up to the peaks as a kid on holiday enough times. Went to uni at Loughborough as well, so know a few bits! I set as a community wiki, so feel free to add more!

Comment: This is a great example of a well supported answer to this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is "how to find a good place", this is what I suggest to do research. In no particular order:

- Go to Google maps around your desireable location and switch on street view
- Search the place on google images to see what are "usual" images in the particular area. Example search query is "[Nottinghamshire landscape](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nottinghamshire%20landscape&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjli_mVrK_VAhVqwFQKHVlQA2gQ_AUICigB&biw=2001&bih=1343#imgrc=CQxGExlQ0OuHpM:)".
- Go to local tourist center, they always have brochures with pictures of the local sight-seeing places. Some areas have [their own websites](http://www.experiencenottinghamshire.com/) of course, which you should explore
- Go to Flickr or other your favourite photo website with geo tags and filter images taken in that area. Or search image by your location, Flickr does provide map with approximate location, for example [see this picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/purefinder/3721875446/in/photolist-6ETzUj-w5E4sh-PQgJ1u-jDkBk8-rBbRmQ-5FL95u-TahniH-tdEsza-NgoATi-GUYSFY-GFyTDs-a6sb76-coLjeq-cFisqh-DwxARZ-aeCsCo-jrd44v-exSkzX-hBbU3J-8Cfnda-bsiBWD-Psia6E-sePGCy-aq9ZhY-i5hy7g-PXmwDn-dz7vog-PAZm5A-jeBtvJ-jn7n9C-cj2DeE-jF3idP-duxGxV-Su8yoN-zqX9UV-9741aZ-fWCrnZ-ajvcaD-REqNwb-HVRPPr-s78Q1C-j35VAs-jXb4FY-jX8zux-jXaYDo-dASFJP-bd91dx-5BgMST-SAuY8b-D5Gte2)
- Same Flickr offers [Map view](https://www.flickr.com/map) which is to me a bit confusing tool